# How to detect a player at Y level 2 anywhere in the world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've made a practice run for parkour in my world and when I fall, I have to `/kill` or fly back up and it is annoying and takes time, so I was wondering if I could use commands to teleport me to a certain position if my Y level is 2 or less. I am in 1.16.3.

I tried to use the `/execute` commands but I don't think I am using it right, this is the command i am trying to use:

```
/execute if entity @p[y=2] run teleport @p 162 10 -652.
```

Anytime I've used this it just teleports me infinitely to the position, even if I am not at Y level 2. What is going on, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

## Simple solution

Let's look at the Minecraft Wiki page on [target selector arguments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments).

> **Position arguments**
>
> `[x=<value>,y=<value>,z=<value>]`
> Define a position in the world the selector starts at, for use with the `distance` argument or the volume arguments, `dx`, `dy` and `dz`. Defining the position alone can be used with a target selector that selects the nearest entity from those coordinates, but it otherwise has no use, so applying it (and only it) to `@e` still selects all entities in the same dimension.

Therefore, you cannot use the position arguments `x`, `y`, and `z` on their own, and it is impossible to select targets on a certain Y level anywhere in the world. You need to give additional information to the target selector.

The most basic way is by using the `distance` argument. This will detect targets within certain distances of the specified position. Here are some examples:

- `@p[x=11,y=22,z=33,distance=5]`: Select targets *exactly* 5 blocks from coordinates (11, 22, 33).
- `@p[x=11,y=22,z=33,distance=3..6]`: Select targets between 3 and 6 blocks from coordinates (11, 22, 33).

You can either use that, or use the volume arguments, `dx`, `dy`, and `dz`. They're a bit to complicated to explain, and the Minecraft Wiki explains them far better than I can ever answer here. Visit the link above for more information.